# How to use operators in array of wheres

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to use `=>` operator in a array of wheres
but the query is using the operator as the binding

```
Model::updateOrCreate([
        ['client_id', $client->id],
        ['created_at', '=>', '2019-05-01 00:00:00',],
    ],
    [
        'client_id' => $client->id,
    ]
);
```

This does not work, the query looks like this

```
[
    "query"    =>
        "select * from `models` where (`client_id` = ? and `created_at` = ?) limit 1",
    "bindings" => [
        0 => 5,
        1 => "=>",
    ],
];
```

I searched the web and could not find the proper documentation for the function 
`addArrayOfWheres`

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`=>` is not a valid operator for clauses, you should use `>=`.

A full list of allowed operators can be found [in the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L176).

```
/**
 * All of the available clause operators.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $operators = [
    '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=', '<=>',
    'like', 'like binary', 'not like', 'ilike',
    '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
    'rlike', 'regexp', 'not regexp',
    '~', '~*', '!~', '!~*', 'similar to',
    'not similar to', 'not ilike', '~~*', '!~~*',
];
```